# How to get automatic package suggestions at command line?

Tags: bash, fedora, command-not-found

I use Fedora 23. In an older version of Fedora (or maybe it was Ubuntu), I used to get package suggestions at the command line (Bash) when a command wasn't found. I liked this.

```
$ glmark2
Command not found
Command glmark2 is provided by package glmark2. 
Would you like to install it? (y/n)
Installed package glmark2.
```

How can I get this feature in Fedora 23?

Comment: as far as I can tell it works in current Fedora by default (at least Workstation).

Comment: Cool. I'm running the MATE spin of Fedora 23. Maybe I'm missing a package.

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/PackageKitCommandNotFound?

Comment: Normally i will type `n` to quit and then manually install via `dnf`, the reason is because there's no download progress/sizes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package on Fedora is called [`PackageKit-command-not-found`](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/PackageKit-command-not-found).

The Fedora package installs a hook in `/etc/profile`, so it's only available in login shells. To make it available in all interactive instanced of bash, add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -e /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh ]; then
  . /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh
fi
```

Comment: It isn't in pkgdb because pkgdb is indexed by source RPMs, and this one is built as a subpackage of the main PackageKit source RPM.

Comment: @mattdm Ah, thanks. Is there a way to look up binary packages on pkgdb or a similar site? I guess there's always rpmfind, but that requires pinpointing a version and architecture.

Comment: Yeah — you can search for it in [Fedora Packages Search](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/), which is a _different_ application meant to be more end-user-useful.  (pkgdb is really a packager-centric view.)

Comment: So, https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/PackageKit-command-not-found

Comment: @mattdm Thanks. I wonder how search operates: [searching for `command-not-found`](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/s/command-not-found) turns up 0 results. Is it searching descriptions only and not package names?

Comment: I'll have to check. I found it by searching for the full string `PackageKit-command-not-found`

Comment: Thanks, I actually wanted to get rid of it.